# Does Windows automatically switch to ethernet when a cable is connected?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, ethernet

When actively using the internet over wi-fi, then plugging in an ethernet cable, does Windows automatically switch to the wired connection? And where can one see what network device the computer is using?

Comment: My experience is quite the opposite; Windows 10 seems to prefer wireless connectivity over wired connectivity. It doesn't automatically switch if the current connection is adequate, but if a wireless network that you're not connected to is offering better metrics than the one you're connecting to, it _will_ ask if you want to switch networks.

Comment: My experience is that Windows doesn't switch adapters after the boot.

Comment: It depends on the adapter in the computer. My laptops both switch to Ethernet when I plug in a LAN cable automatically.  My metric in the Advanced Properties is default.

Comment: If on WiFi, and you plug in an Ethernet connection, just select Airplane Mode to force switching to the wired connection.

Comment: No. When there are multiple network adapters, Windows 10 will prefer use the one with the lowest interface metric. This can be set in the advanced TCP/IP configuration for your preferred adapter. If you need help with this, reply to the comment and I'll post screenshots.You can check the values of the automatic metric for each interface by running this in an Administrator CMD prompt: `netsh interface ip show address`